# Build libraries in external folder of AOSP source code

Tags: android-source, libselinux

I noticed that a simple

```
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch
$ aosp_hammerhead-eng
$ make -j16
```

Would not build also the external libraries in the `./external` folder.

How am I supposed to build source code in such folder?

In particular, I am modifying source code in the libselinux in `./external/selinux/libselinux/src/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, by using the `mm` command, it is possible to build all of the modules in the current directory.

So, if you are in `./external/selinux/libselinux/` you can build all code inside such directory just by typing the command `mm`.

I also found that the same code I was modifying inside the  `./external/selinux/libselinux/` is also located in  `./external/libselinux/`. However, this directory is linked to the `make -j16` command.